# Win32: API calls to list available network shares on a server?

Tags: winapi, samba, smb, network-shares

Assume I have access to a SMB server at IP 1.2.3.4, how can I determine the list of available shares?

Windows Explorer can do it when I enter a UNC path \\1.2.3.4\ - but command prompt "dir \\1.2.3.4\" fails!

I've tried the usual FindFirstFile/FindNext calls - which I use successfully to read the files and directories on each share, but they don't work directly on the server root.

Ideally, I need something that works for XP onwards.

**Edit:** I want to do this programatically, rather than from command line. Redirecting and parsing the output from 'net view 1.2.3.4' would work, but I'm ideally looking for an API for this job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the docs there's a [`NetShareEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525387(VS.85).aspx) and a [`WNetEnumResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385449(VS.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 4):

net view \\1.2.3.4

Check out http://www.ss64.com/nt/net_share.html

Edit: If you want to do this programmatically, it looks like [NetShareEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525387(VS.85).aspx) would work.

Comment: +1: Thanks, that's useful. I was hoping for an API-based way of doing this. parsing the output of net view would work, but...

Comment: If you want to see all shares (including hidden ones) then use "net view \\1.2.3.4 /ALL"

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can use WMI to get this information.  Check [this post](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_wmi_shares.htm) for some neat PowerShell tutorials that show now to use the Win32_Share WMI object.

Answer (score 0):

Never use WMI (not installed natively)
Use Win32 api to enumerate shares, posted millions of times on google groups( win32)

Comment: WMI is there since Windows XP so again, stop making stuff up.